# npm install yields warnings about watchify peers that I can't seem to correct

Tags: node.js, npm, installation

Running npm install raises the following warnings:

> npm WARN karma-browserify@5.1.0 requires a peer of browserify@>=10 <14 but none was installed.
>
> npm WARN karma-browserify@5.1.0 requires a peer of watchify@>=3 <4 but none was installed.

I ran the following:

```
npm install browserify
npm install watchify
```

Running

```
 watchify --version
```

yields

> watchify v3.7.0 (in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/watchify)
>
> browserify v13.1.0 (in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/watchify/node_modules/browserify)

which match the requisites in the warning, but running npm install again yields the same warnings. Did I do something wrong? Is there something else I should do? I admit I do not understand what the warning means with "peer" and tried googling but did not find the answer

Comment: Try this: npm install --save-dev karma-browserify browserify watchify (--save-dev only if you want add packages in dev-dependency)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost on the right path. Try running

```
npm install browserify watchify --save
```

Like @JacopoBrovida has mentioned

Unless your modules are persisted onto your `package.json`, npm wouldn't register them.

Comment: worked. Before trying your solution, I installed the full version of x-code too. previously I only had the command line version. Not sure which fixed it